# Equivalent to System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.GetFormat in WPF

Tags: wpf, pinvoke

Is there an equivalent to the `System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.GetFormat` method in Windows Presentation Foundation or will I end up having to invoke the Win32 `RegisterClipboardFormat` API via platform invoke instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A-ha! It's `System.Windows.DataFormats.GetDataFormat`.